# can I define variables in terms of other variables in less/xCss

Tags: css, less

I would like to do something like this:

```
@pixelToEmConversion: 1 / 16;
@width: 988px * @pixelToEmConversion;
```

but it doens't seem to work like I expected it would, and I can't find anything that looks promising.

I was using xCSS for a while, but it has the same problem.  Maybe I am overlooking something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work for me

```
.ttt {
    @pixelToEmConversion: 1 / 16;
    @width: 988px * @pixelToEmConversion;
    width: @width;
}
```

After compiling I get .ttt{width:61.75px;} that seems to be correct